# Como puedo hacer para cambiar el titulo de un JFrame desde otro JFrame

Tags: java, jframe, parametros, static

Lo que tengo es:
**JFramePrincipal()**
donde el setTitle("APP") y un botón() que me envía al JFramLogin

En el **JFrameLogin()**
Se realiza el login y se obtiene un string con el "Usuario : ADMINISTRADOR" .
este dato lo quisiera agregar al titulo de la ventana principal JFramePrincipal
el cual tendría que quedar del siguiente modo " APP Usuario : ADMINISTRADOR ".

En el problema que me encuentro es que no se como hacer para acceder al método JFramePrincipal.setTitle() desde el JFrameLogin() porque el método setTitle() no es un método static.
¿Quizás esto se realiza de otro modo ? muchas gracias desde ya !!

Comment: Hola, te invito a hacer el [tour] para aprender las reglas básicas del sitio y de paso ganar tu primer medalla. Te invito también a ver [ask]. Debes agregar el código que llevas hecho para que podamos ayudarte con tu problema.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que lo ideal seria usar JPanel, pero igual voy a mostrar como hacer con 2 JFrame.

Tienes que crear los 2 JFrame y darle eventos a los respectivos botones (acá estoy en el Main.java)

```
FramePrincipal framePrincipal = new FramePrincipal();

FrameLogin frameLogin = new FrameLogin();
frameLogin.dispose(); // Esto para que no se vea al abrir.
```

Una vez instanciados e inicializados estos componentes, se le agregan eventos a los botones.

```
framePrinicial.getGoToLoginButton().addActionListener(e -> {
    frameLogin.setVisible(true);
    framePrincipal.dispose(); // Se oculta (no se cierra)
});
```

Eso era para el botón que abre la ventana de Login, ahora agregamos el evento al botón, que vuelve a abrir la ventana principal con el nuevo titulo.

```
frameLogin.getLoginButton().addActionListener(e -> {
    String title = "APP Usuario: " + frameLogin.getUserField().getText();
    framePrincipal.setTitle(title);
    framePrincipal.setVisible(true) // Se vuelve a visualizar la ventana cerrada.

    frameLogin.getUserField().setText(""); //Se limpia el campo de texto.
    frameLogin.dispose(); //Ocultamos la ventana.
});
```

La ventana FrameLogin debe tener el campo `setDefualtCloseOperation(DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE)`, con el fin de que el usuario no cierre la ventana de Login, ya que ocultamos la otra ventana y ocasiona que el programa se cierre.

Debe quedar algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para aclarar rápidamente lo que se hice:

- FramePrincipal y FrameLogin son 2 clases que extienden de JFrame (no digo que sea lo correcto hacerlo)
- El FramePrincipal tiene como siempre su `EXIT_ON_CLOSE` para cerrar el programa, mientras que el FrameLogin tiene la propiedad de `DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE`
- Cuando se hace `frameLogin.dispose()` no se termina el programa, facilmente puede recuperar la ventana con `frameLogin.setVisible(true)`, en el caso que halla una ventana por arriba y esta no se cierre primero.